# What security measures should i take when getting code input from the user and running it like Codepen?

Tags: reactjs, security, xss, secure-coding

I am creating something similar to Codpen with React, where the user can enter HTML and JS code,
then I'm running it inside an `iframe`, giving it `srcDoc` of the user's input. Something like:

```
const render = () => {
  const htmlCode = // the data from the user's input
  const jsCode = // the data from the user's input
  const input = `<html><body>${htmlCode}</body><script type="text/javascript">${jsCode}. </script></html>`;
  return <iframe srcDoc={input}/>
}
```

I'm kind of clueless right now about the vulnerabilities I'm exposed to.
Could you direct me to some steps I should take?

Comment: by using sandbox attribute it seem you can prevent some vulnerability \
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/ \
codepen iframe: 
```
<iframe src="url" name="CodePen" allowfullscreen="true" sandbox="allow-downloads allow-forms allow-modals allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" allow="accelerometer; ambient-light-sensor; camera; encrypted-media; geolocation; gyroscope; microphone; midi; payment; vr" allowtransparency="true" allowpaymentrequest="true" iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: that's great, thanks!